# Uncaught ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

why do I have this problem? I'm trying to get an output to the user name in the site. but it keeps giving me this problem!

I ant it to write me that the user name is not correct when im starting with a number or it is blanked at all- it gives me nothing.

please help me I am sitting on this above an hour:((

**Snippet**

```js
function validateForm() {
  var res = true;
  res = userNameVal() && res;
  return res;
}

function userNameVal() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var msgBox = document.getElementById("userNameCheck");
  if (userName.length == 0) {
    msgBox.innerHTML = "You must enter user name";
    msgBox.style.color = "red"
    return false;
  }
  if (!isLetter(userName[0])) {
    msgBox.innerHTML = "User name must start with a letter ";
    msgBox.style.color = "red";
    return false;
  }
  msgBox.innerHTML = "";
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <table class="table3">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="username">User Name:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" 
          name="username" 
          id="username" 
          onchange="userNameVal()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="userNameCheck"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" 
        value="submit" 
        onclick="return validateForm()"/>
        <input type="reset" value="reset" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Where and how do you load in your script into that page?

Comment: You don't need the "return" in `onclick="return validateForm()"`

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Modern browsers have [built-in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) that can do all this for you without any JavaScript.  See alternative to your code here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz42emqr/show).

Comment: ^because I have to. it is a task.

Comment: @Alex Yes you do. If an `onXXX` expression returns `false`, it's equivalent to doing `event.preventDefault()`. So you have to return the function's value.

Comment: You don't need to call the function in both the submit button's `onclick` and the form's `onsubmit`. `onsubmit` is sufficient.

Comment: Are you sure the function definitions are at top-level like you show? This would happen if `validateForm()` were nested inside another function.